# Cannot find image picker component with 'paste image url' field\tab

Tags: reactjs

I am cannot find image picker component with 'paste image url' field\tab.
For example like Google image search has.
If such components for React already exist?
I can not find them using search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any packages, but it's not hard to implement on your own. Here is a quick example I threw together, is this what you're looking for?

```js
class ImagePicker extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    showImage: true,
    src: 'http://www.unixstickers.com/image/data/stickers/react/badge/React-JS.sh.png'
  };
  
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      src: e.target.value,
      showImage: false
    });
  };
  
  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({
      showImage: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { src, showImage } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        Enter image url<br/>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={src} />
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} >Load Image URL</button>
        <hr/>
        {showImage && <img src={src} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ImagePicker/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I would like to have both 'paste image url' and 'choose file' fields. Just like Google has. But thanks, that helped me to start.